# Gitlab change file rule is not working as per the documentation

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a terraform gitlab cicd pipe. The plan is to trigger the pipe based on changes in the files on the environment(dev and prod)
I got it inspired from https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2023/06/14/managing-multiple-environments-with-terraform-and-gitlab-ci/
See below the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
fmt-development:
  stage: format
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./development
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform fmt
  allow_failure: true
  rules:
    #- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="merge_request_event"
    -  changes:
        - development/**/*

init-development:
  stage: prepare
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./development
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT 
    - gitlab-terraform init

  rules:
    #- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="merge_request_event"
    -  changes:
        - development/**/*

validate-development:
  stage: validate
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./development
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform init
    - gitlab-terraform validate
  rules:
    #- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="merge_request_event"
    -  changes:
        - development/**/*

build-development:
  stage: build
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./development
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform plan
    - gitlab-terraform plan-json

  rules:
    #- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="merge_request_event"
    -  changes:
        - development/**/*

deploy-development:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./development
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform apply
  dependencies:
    - build-development
  when: manual

  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=="main"
      changes:
        - development/**/*

refresh-development:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./development
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform apply -refresh-only
  dependencies:
    - build-development
  when: manual
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=="main"
      changes:
        - development/**/*

fmt-production:
  stage: format
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./production
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform fmt
  allow_failure: true

  rules:
    #- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="merge_request_event"
    -  changes:
        - production/**/*

init-production:
  stage: prepare
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./production
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT 
    - gitlab-terraform init

  rules:
    #- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="merge_request_event"
    -  changes:
        - production/**/*

validate-production:
  stage: validate
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./production
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform init
    - gitlab-terraform validate

  rules:
    #- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="merge_request_event"
    -  changes:
        - production/**/*

build-production:
  stage: build
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./production
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform plan
    - gitlab-terraform plan-json

  rules:
    #- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="push" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=="merge_request_event"
    -  changes:
        - production/**/*

deploy-production:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./production
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform apply
  dependencies:
    - build-production
  when: manual


  rules:
    - if:  $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=="main"
      changes:
        - production/**/*

refresh-production:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    TF_ROOT: ./production
  script:
    - cd ${TF_ROOT}
    - echo $TF_ROOT
    - gitlab-terraform apply -refresh-only
  dependencies:
    - build-production
  when: manual

  rules:
    - if:  $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH=="main"
      changes:
        - production/**/*
```

However, when I push a change onto files in  `development/` both dev and prod pipes are getting triggered.

Any help is appreciated